# How to disable git 'Push Results' dialog in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit

After a **push to upstream** git operation the eclipse IDE shows a helpful dialog which provides information about the push operation (shown below).

Is there a way to prevent this dialog from popping up?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way would be to select, when doing the push, the following checkbox:

```
Show final report dialog only when it differs from this confirmation report
```

[The help page](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/Tasks.html#Push_Confirmation) mentions:

> if you only want to get a report after executing the push if the result differs from this preview.

[image: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.egit.doc/help/EGit/User_Guide/images/Egit-0.9-push-wizard-confirm-push.png]

That way this dialog box ([introduced in Egit1.1](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/1.1#More_information_displayed_in_merge.2C_fetch_and_push_results_dialogs)) won't pop-up if the push went as expected.

Comment: I know I must be missing something obvious but how do I get to this dialog? This dialog is not displayed when I do push operations. My EGit plugins are version: 3.0.3....

Comment: On another note, I would ideally like to push from the commit dialog (using the very useful 'Commit and Push') and then not have to confirm any further messages; would I have to configure the 'Push To' dialog then for every push?

Comment: @mxro I don't have a 3.0.3 to test on, but I suspect this checkbox should then be available in the Egit options somewhere in the Egit settings.

Comment: These would be under Team / Git? Can't find them there - which would be the best version of EGit to use; I think I used the one that came with Kepler SR1. Thanks!!!

Comment: @mxro Looking at https://github.com/eclipse/egit/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.ui/src/org/eclipse/egit/ui/internal/push/PushOperationUI.java#L217-L229, I don't see any way to avoid that `PushResultDialog` UI.

Comment: Looks like it, thanks! So using the Push To dialog looks like the best option within eclipse!

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions allow for disabling the confirmation in Windows > Preferences, see image below

[image]

Comment: Awesome, this was introduced in newer eGit-Versions, love it!